# assign string to variable with if else condition

Tags: ksh

I have written the code. to check the variable value if it GL then SQLGL should XDOAPPL, if AP then SQLAP should assign XDOAPPL variable. but it is giving me the error.

```
APPL=$1
x=AP
y=GL
echo "Value of x = $x and y = $y."
a=SQLAP
b=SQLGL

if [["$APPL" = "AP"]};
then
XDOAPPL=${a}
echo "AP XDOAPPL =$XDOAPPL"
elif [["$APPL" = "GL"]];
then
XDOAPPL=${b}
echo "GL XDOAPPL =$XDOAPPL"
else
echo "Nothing to go"
fi
```

Comment: There are multiple syntax error in your code. Please run it though [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: “it is giving me the error” So **copy-paste the error message into your question**.

Comment: @DeclanGallagher I have rolled back your edit to the question. The whole _point_ of this question lies in the syntax errors. Do not correct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `[[ ]]`, you must leave a space between `[[` or `]]` and the content.
You also mistyped a `}` instead of a `]` in the first `if`.

Here is the correct code :

```
APPL=$1
x=AP
y=GL
echo "Value of x = $x and y = $y."
a=SQLAP
b=SQLGL

if [[ "$APPL" = "AP" ]];
then
  XDOAPPL=${a}
  echo "AP XDOAPPL = $XDOAPPL"
elif [[ "$APPL" = "GL" ]];
then
  XDOAPPL=${b}
  echo "GL XDOAPPL = $XDOAPPL"
else
  echo "Nothing to go"
fi
```